# UScensus2010 package's areaPoly function

Tags: r

Hi I use the following R code to get population density on blockgroup level.

```
library(UScensus2010)
install.blkgrp(‘linux’)
library(UScensus2010blkgrp)

data(texas.blkgrp10)

a = texas.blkgrp10
b = cbind(geolink=a$fips,area = areaPoly(a),
      population = a$P0010001,
      pop_den=a$P0010001/areaPoly(a),
      num_house = a$H0010001,
      house_den=a$H0010001/areaPoly(a))
```

What are the units of measurement for areaPoly(a)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak directly to the USCensus2010 package (`install.blkgrp('windows')` does not appear to work...), but in the Census TIGER files, from which this data is generated, the units are **square meters**. You can see this by looking at the TIGER file metadata, as follows:

```
## BG=Block Group; FIPS 48 is Texas
url   <- "http://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/BG/2010/tl_2010_48_bg10.zip"
tf    <- tempfile()
td    <- tempdir()
download.file(url,tf, mode="wb")     # download shapefile archive of Texas BG Boundaries
unzip(tf, exdir=td)                  # unzip into directory td
library(XML)
# metadata is in *.shp.xml
doc   <- xmlTreeParse(paste(td,"tl_2010_48_bg10.shp.xml", sep="/"), useInternalNodes=TRUE)
doc["//attr[attrlabl='ALAND10']"]    # metadata for ALAND10 field in attributes table
# [[1]]
# <attr>
#   <attrlabl>ALAND10</attrlabl>
#   <attrdef>2010 Census land area (square meters)</attrdef>
#   <attrdefs>U.S. Census Bureau</attrdefs>
#   <attrdomv>
#     <edom>
#       <edomv>0 to 9,999,999,999,999</edomv>
#       <edomvd>Blank</edomvd>
#       <edomvds>U.S. Census Bureau</edomvds>
#     </edom>
#   </attrdomv>
# </attr>
```

Comment: Thanks. This can obtain what I am looking for.

Comment: Since you're new to SO, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).